# Is it safe to install several apps from ports at the same time?

Tags: freebsd

Can multiple `make install`s cause problems for the package system?

For example:

```
cd /usr/ports/*/nmap && make install
cd /usr/ports/*/firefox && make install
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if two ports have the same dependancy, try to build it at the same time, one or both builds will fail. It's better to build ports serially (making a meta port of all the ports you want to install is a good idea if you're going to do it on several machines) and run make with a `-j #` to increase concurrency where it's able .

Comment: +1 - I'd also add that I try to build the port with the most dependencies first.  If you're doing this for multiple machines it helps to use something like `radmind` or `puppet` to manage your machines (install on one box as a template and push out the changes to the rest of your environment)

Comment: It's not a big problem for me to restart the build. Can this corrupt the package database?

Comment: Do not run `make` with `-j`, ports system is already aware of this and by default will run one make process per CPU where it's possible